# yfinance gui string not defined?

Tags: python

I'm trying to build a program to graph data from yfinance. It will build the GUI but when I press the search button I get an error name **name 'ticker_info' is not defined.** But shouldn't ticker_info be defined as the string variable in tickerE?

How can I simply take the input and use it in the function at the bottom?

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import pyautogui
from tkinter import *
import keyboard
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import pyplot

def save_info():
    startdate_info = startdate.get
    enddate_info = enddate.get
    ticker_info = tickerE.get
    inspect_info = inspectE.get
    print(inspect_info, enddate_info, ticker_info, startdate_info)

screen = Tk()
screen.geometry("450x550")


startdate = StringVar()
start_date = Label(text = "Enter start date in YYYY-MM-DD format: ")
start_date.place(x = 15, y = 70)
startdate_entry = Entry(textvariable = startdate, width = "30")
startdate_entry.place(x = 15, y = 120)

enddate = StringVar()
end_date = Label(text = "Enter end date in YYYY-MM-DD format: ")
end_date.place(x = 15, y = 170)
enddate_entry = Entry(textvariable = enddate, width = "30")
enddate_entry.place(x = 15, y = 220)

tickerE = StringVar()
ticker_label = Label(text = "Ticker symbol:  ")
ticker_label.place(x = 15, y = 270)
ticker = Entry(textvariable = tickerE, width = "30")
ticker.place(x = 15, y = 320)

inspectE = StringVar()
inspect_label = Label(text = "What would you like to analyze  ")
inspect_label.place(x = 15, y = 270)
inspect_label = Label(text = "(Open, High, Low, Close, Adj Close, Volume)? ")
inspect_label.place(x = 15, y = 320)
inspect = Entry(textvariable = inspectE, width = "30")
inspect.place(x = 15, y = 370)

search = Button(screen,text = "Search", width = "30", height = "2", command = save_info, bg = "grey")
search.place(x = 14, y = 410)


newtime = yf.download(ticker_info, start = startdate_info, end = enddate_info)
print(newtime)
def adjusted_close(ticker, newtime):
    newtime[inspect].plot()
    plt.xlabel("Date")
    plt.ylabel(inspect)
    plt.title(ticker + " " + inspect + " "  + "Data")
    plt.show()
adjusted_close(ticker, newtime)
```

Comment: `ticker_info` is a scoped variable inside the function `save_info`. You can't access it outside of the function. To do so, you'll need to return the variables at the end of `save_info`, for e.g. `return ticker_info, inspect_info` and then assign it once you call `save_info`.

Comment: 'ticker_info' is a local variable inside `save_info()`.  It is not accessible elsewhere, and indeed *doesn't even exist* except during a call to that function.  But you're trying to use it immediately after setting up your widgets; the user hasn't even seen the Entries yet, much less had any chance to type anything into them.

Comment: @lionbigcat I moved that save_info(): function below the gui code and added return ticker_info, inspect_info to the bottom of that function. Then called save_info() just above newtime and now I get the error 'ticker_info' is not defined?

Comment: @ColterGrantRobinson update your post above.